# How to split a Gradle task into pure compilation and pure execution tasks from CLI?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm working on splitting a custom test task into build and test phase (I want to build the sources with Java 8 and run them with Java 11 without recompilation).
The task is defined [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/90ada50f8c8b2797c30aae0e032d4b18cbc5b69c/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/build.gradle#L183)

Running the task with `-x test` flag doesn't disable the tests. I want to be able to do it all from command line in order to execute the task as part of a Jenkins job.

So far I failed to come up with a solution other than chaining 5 bash commands and adding the tasks from `--dry-run` to the `./gradle` command and later excluding them with `-x`, but I believe there must be a more elegant approach.

If I missed some information required to provide some answers, please let me know, I'll be happy to fill you in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is exactly what the Java plugin does with its default tasks:

- `compileTestJava` is the task responsible for compiling the tests.
- `test` is the task responsible for running the tests, and it expresses a dependency on `compileTestJava`

So you would model your tasks the same way:

- One `JavaCompile` task, configured with Java 8, to compile the tests.
- One `Test` task, configured with Java 11, to run the tests, with a dependency on the previous task.

Then the up-to-date system of Gradle should do the trick, that is only run the `Test` task when the `JavaCompile` task is up-to-date.

And in order to run only the test compilation, you would invoke just the matching task. Assuming it defines its own dependencies properly, it would do only what's required.

If you need more specific guidance on how to defined these tasks, add more information to the question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm unclear on how to define the tasks. The one I want to split has an explicit `dependsOn` task, but it's not the only source of dependencies, there are more and I'm not sure how to extract them to another task. What info would you need to assist here?